# Import external libraries Kivy without buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, python-3.5, kivy-language

Recently I've been working on a project that involves a phone taking a picture, processing it in some way, and returning the output on the screen. In order to do this, I would have to use openCV, but when I try to "import cv2" in the Kivy code using the launcher, the app crashes immediately after I run it. I realize now that the reason this happens is because the Kivy launcher by itself can only do basic functions like print and such and there must be extra steps needed to use external libraries. I tried to use Buildozer to create a package for android, but soon found out that it only would work for linux computers, while I use Windows.

Essentially, my question is: Is there any way to include an external library in Kivy without using buildozer? And if there is, could you please describe it or post a link to a webpage that contains instructions(as I am fairly new to programming and am somewhat of a noob)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try python-for-android. 
But the easiest way - install virtual box to your PC, download kivy/buildozer for VirtualBox( it calles Virtual Machine (for Android/buildozer)) here below: https://kivy.org/#download and then just connect downloaded vmdk-disk to VirtualBox, and then use this. Everything is prepared, you don't need to install kivy or buildozer.

You will spend about 30-40 minutes.

Comment: in the vmdk that you must download - installed Xubuntu 12, it is Linux distr.